# Problems with querying when a value is null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am using php to query a database for one piece of information from each of 10 separate tables currently. The problem with using multiple queries is that it is extremely slow when accessing the web page that uses all of this information. I cannot seem to get all of the information back that I am wanting when one of the values does not exist due to the WHERE... statement.

For instance, my single queries are all in this format:

```
SELECT eval_id FROM eval WHERE user_id = $id;
```

My multiple table query looks like this:

```
SELECT eval_id,list_id,tab_id
FROM eval,list,tab
WHERE eval.user_id = $id
  AND list.user_id = $id
  AND tab.user_id = $id;
```

I tried to combine these queries into one large query, but when the user_id of one does not exist in the table, the comparison in the WHERE... statement screws up the entire query. Does anyone know the best way to retrieve all of this information?

Assume that the tables are "eval, list, and tab," and their id's are *_id respectively. What would be the best way to query this even if eval does not contain a result where the user_id = $id?

Comment: `AND NULL <> eval.user_id` ?

Comment: I am looking for something very dynamic. In the event that eval_id does yield a result, I want it to give me that value. Will this yield a result in that case?

Comment: Nope. it will ignore it if the usre_id returns null

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT eval.eval_id, list.list_id
FROM user
JOIN eval ON eval.user_id = user.id
JOIN list ON list.user_id = user.id
WHERE user.id = $id
```

Hope it can help you.

Update: Just think about other solution:

```
SELECT eval_id as id, "eval" as table
FROM eval WHERE eval.user_id = $id

UNION

SELECT list_id as id, "list" as table
FROM list WHERE list.user_id = $id
```

Comment: I have this setup currently, and it takes to long for 10 queries to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You could use either of the following to your query in the `WHERE` statement:

```
AND TABLE.TABLE_id <> null //null 

AND TABLE.TABLE_id <> 'null' //String null

AND TABLE.TABLE_id <> '' //empty String
```

Check your database to see what kind of empty value your `id` is returning and choose the addition that matches it.

Also, while `LEFT JOIN`s may be better looking in a query, they are not always faster so make sure you test it before using.

Comment: Is it okay to incorporate multiple of these into a single query? For instance, eval.user_id = $id OR eval.user_id <> null AND list.user_id = $id OR list.user_id <> null

Comment: Yes, the `WHERE` statement can have multiple checks